# OSError: Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm getting this error as an **UnknownError** with the data augmentation function for a CNN I developed using Keras and Tensorflow as mentioned below.

```
testGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255.0,
    rotation_range = 45,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    zoom_range = [0.5,1.0],
    data_format = 'channels_last',
    dtype = tf.float32,
)

test_generator = dataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    "D:\\Data\\", target_size = (image_height, image_width), batch_size=batch_size,  
    class_mode = 'sparse', shuffle=True, seed=123, color_mode = 'grayscale',
)

print("No of augmented training data: " + str(len(test_generator)))
```

The execution terminates after the model.evaluation function.

```
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-455b71844aa2> in <module>
     12 evaluation = model.evaluate(
     13    test_generator,
---> 14    batch_size=batch_size,
     15 )
     16
```

It worked earlier well without any problem. Suddenly started to appear in this error. I have no clue to fix this out. I'm glad if anyone could give me an idea to fix the bug.

Comment: maybe remove the batch_size parameter in model.evaluate? Generators have a fixed batch size that cannot be changed

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried it as well. Then it points out the error to the previous line, test_generator. I think something went wrong with my test_generator here. I removed the batch_size in there also. But still have the error.

Comment: Then include the complete traceback and code that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like batch_size hasn't been defined yet. Try defining batch size, or using a #.

Comment: It's in the previous code section. I defined it with image_height and image_width